# Unable to instantiate receiver - Class not found

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hoping someone can help me out as this is driving me crazy.

Trying to implement on boot completed but my receiver class is not being found.

Here is my manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.myapp.services.StartAlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

here is my broadcast receiver

```
package com.myapp.services;

public class StartAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context; 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
    .......
```

Ive double checked spelling, case and location but it keeps throwing the class not found exception. Also tried cleaning the project, moving the receiver into the default package etc .. .

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I am declaring a context , context = c

But I had this set after the toast. D'oh